# Log.i does not execute

Tags: android, sqlite, logcat, sqliteopenhelper, android-database

I am very new to android programming. I want to use SQLiteOpenHelper class to do some database operations. Here is my SqliteController class that extends SQLiteOpenHelper:

```
public class SqliteController extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
Context context;

public SqliteController(Context context) {
    super(context, "sectionsDB", null, 1);
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query;
    query = "CREATE TABLE Sections ( chapterName TEXT, sectionName TEXT, body TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(query);
    Log.i("tablecreation", "table created");
}
}
```

(I have just mentioned the part that I have problem with)
in my main activity I have created instance of above class in onCreate method of activity like this:

```
SqliteController controller = new SqliteController(this);
```

I want to populate database by reading from xml file once in onCreate method of SqliteController so after newing SqliteController in main activity I don't want to do any operation with database. If I add `controller.getWritableDatabase();` it seems that I have some operations to do with it but all I do is in SqliteController class. Any suggestion?

Comment: I know but what is your comment's relation with my question? @saeed

Comment: you  add  controller.getWritableDatabase(); in your activity

Comment: let me know the result

Comment: I have edited my post, but I think it,s not the same question as you mentioned. @laalto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add something like this:

```
 SqliteController controller = new SqliteController(this);
 controller.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: It works! but I don't know what does this line of code do?

Comment: Does onCreate method execute without it?

Comment: You need the second line because **controller.getWritableDatabase();** _Create and/or open a database that will be used for reading and writing._ [look this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html)

Comment: I just want to create and populate it once so I won't do anything with database that I get from controller.getWritableDatabase()